# Django ORM individual query raw SQLs are different when they are bound with OR

Tags: sql, django

**I apologize for formatting eyesores in advance. Feel free to edit my question for better readability.**

I have four models:

```py
class Datasets(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    description = models.TextField()

class Assay(models.Model):
    dataset = models.ForeignKey(Datasets)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=150)

class Compounds(models.Model):
    dataset = models.ForeignKey(Datasets)
    name = models.TextField()
    deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Assays(models.Model):
    compound = models.ForeignKey(Compounds)
    assay = models.ForeignKey(Assay)
    value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=30, decimal_places=16)
    deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I am building queries with user input depending on the `Assay` picked. I am using `JOIN`s to filter results based on reverse relations. User picks the `Assay` and I filter the compounds based on the selection. Users can also pick 'No Assay' option, which should return the compounds with no registered assays (i.e. no entries in `Assays` model for that compound).

```py
selected_assay_id = 5 # Received from frontend
no_assay_option_selected = True/False # Received from frontend
dataset_id = 1
filter_query = Q()

filter_query.add(Q(**{
        'assays__assay__id': selected_assay_id,
        'assays__compound__id': F('id'),
        'assays__deleted': False
    }), Q.OR)

if no_assay_option_selected:
     filter_query.add(~Q(**{
            'assays__deleted': False,
            'assays__compound__id': F('id')
         }), Q.OR)

compounds = Compounds.objects.filter(filter_query, dataset__id=dataset_id).distinct()
```

When I pick an assay, it works great. When I pick 'No Assay', it works great. But when I pick an assay and also 'No Assay', all the compounds are returned instead of the ones with the picked assay and 'no assay'. When I checked the raw SQL queries, I realized latter query has an additional piece:

```sql
-- Only 'No Assay' option selected
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM "compounds" WHERE (
  NOT ("compounds"."id" IN
        (SELECT U1."compound_id" FROM "compounds" U0
          INNER JOIN "assays" U1 ON (U0."id" = U1."compound_id")
          WHERE U1."compound_id" = (U0."id")) AND "compounds"."id" IN
            (SELECT U1."compound_id" FROM "assays" U1
              WHERE U1."deleted" = False)
      )
  AND "compounds"."dataset_id" = 1 AND "compounds"."deleted" = False
)


-- An assay is selected
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM "compounds" 
INNER JOIN "assays" ON ("compounds"."id" = "assays"."compound_id") 
WHERE (
  "assays"."assay_id" = 5
  AND "assays"."compound_id" = ("compounds"."id") 
  AND "assays"."deleted" = False 
  AND "compounds"."dataset_id" = 1 
  AND "compounds"."deleted" = False
)


-- An assay and 'No Assay' option selected
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM "compounds" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "assays" ON ("compounds"."id" = "assays"."compound_id") 
WHERE (
  (
    (
      "assays"."assay_id" = 5 
      AND "assays"."compound_id" = ("compounds"."id") 
      AND "assays"."deleted" = False
    ) OR NOT (
      "compounds"."id" IN 
      (SELECT U1."compound_id" FROM "compounds" U0 
        INNER JOIN "assays" U1 ON (U0."id" = U1."compound_id") 
        WHERE (U1."compound_id" = (U0."id") AND U1."id" = ("assays"."id"))
      ) AND "compounds"."id" IN 
        (SELECT U1."compound_id" FROM "assays" U1 
          WHERE (U1."deleted" = False AND U1."id" = ("assays"."id"))
      )
    )
  )
  AND "compounds"."dataset_id" = 1 AND "compounds"."deleted" = False
)
```

This is the extra piece in last query: `AND U1."id" = ("assays"."id")` that causes funky results. When I remove it and run the raw query, I get the desired results.

My question is: why is Django doing this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have stumbled onto an actual Django bug here. The behaviour persists even when doing an `INNER JOIN`. If you modify your filter contructor in the `no_assay_option_selected` if block to use a `Q.AND` (even though it doesn't make logical sense to make such a query), you'll find that an `INNER JOIN` query is generated, with the `AND U1."id" = ("assays"."id")` statement still present.

There is a workaround you can use, however:

```
filter_query = Q(
    assays__assay__id=selected_assay_id,
    assays__deleted=False
)

if no_assay_option_selected:
     filter_query |= ~Q(
         id__in=Assays.objects.filter(deleted=False).values_list('compound_id'))
     )

compounds = Compounds.objects.filter(filter_query, dataset__id=dataset_id).distinct()
```

Notice I've also removed your use of `'assays__compound__id': F('id')` in constructing the queries. It's unnecessary, since that's the condition that the join is made `ON`, so tacking it on as a `WHERE` does nothing useful.

The SQL that gets generated by the above should be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM "compounds" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "assays" ON ("compounds"."id" = "assays"."compound_id") 
WHERE (
  (
    (
      "assays"."assay_id" = 5 
      AND "assays"."deleted" = False
    ) OR NOT (
      "compounds"."id" IN
      (SELECT U0."compound_id" FROM "assays" U0 WHERE U0."deleted" = false)
    )
  )
  AND "compounds"."dataset_id" = 1 AND "compounds"."deleted" = False
)
```

Which is what you want, as far as I can tell. The join still needs to be a `LEFT OUTER` to include compounds without assays.

Comment: It works, thank you! I still need my solution (https://stackoverflow.com/a/57600739) for this to work though. I think what I need requires `INNER JOIN`, I don't think it will work with `OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: Glad to hear it works! I'm surprised that you need to use `assays__isnull=False` (or an `INNER JOIN` in general) though, because that would exclude compounds without assays (but it would include compounds with deleted assays).

Comment: Actually I take my previous comment back, I don't need `.filter(assays__isnull=False)`. I made a mistake yesterday. Your solution works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

I figured Django ORM prefers using `OUTER JOIN` over `INNER JOIN` even when inner join is exactly what you want, like in my case. Luckily there's a way to force ORM using inner join:

```py
Compounds.objects.filter(assays__isnull=False).filter(filter_query, dataset__id=dataset_id).distinct()
```

The first filter tells using `INNER JOIN` is safe ([Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45557883/1004334)).